# Terraform Azure - No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

im using the Azure free trial account to run terraform commands via visual studio.
I have installed Azure CLI and I can perform the authentication successfully.
However, what I put code to create new resource & use Terraform plan then it just gives "No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration." msg and nothing happens.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.c[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdjDu.png)om/noWHm.png)

it should give the 1 add resource

Comment: can you please run the command to list the files available in your directory by using "ls" command and provide the screen shot here  @VishalRampure

Comment: The link to your screenshot is broken, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Terraform infrastructure doesn't match the configuration files Issue.

The message "`No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration`" typically means that the current state of your infrastructure, as known by Terraform, is the same as the configuration defined in your `.tf` files.

But in the next step when you run the `terraform show` it is showing as `no state`.  Which only happens when accidental deletion or removal of state file from your local directory which happens after running `terraform plan` command.

In the Initial steps:

***step 1:***
[image]

***step 2:***
run the command `terraform plan`:

[image]

***step 3:***
If the state file exists in local and runs the command
`terraform show`:

[image]

[image]

***step 4:***
when the state file removed accidentally or removed

[image]

And when I run the command `terraform show`

[image]

you can confirm the existence of `.tfstate` file using `ls` command

[image]